# How to install glibc with debugging info on CentOS 5.5

Tags: c, centos, glibc

I am working through Zed Shaw's Learn C the Hard Way.

In the chapter on Valgrind, the section ["What you should see"](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/learn-c-the-hard-waych5.html#x10-320005.3) has line numbers for various glibc functions.

I've determined that (obviously) my CentOS 5.5 install has the non-debug glibc installed. However yum does not list glibc-dbg (or anything similar:

```
[nzucker:~/projects/lcthw]$ yum info \*glibc\* | grep Name
Name       : glibc
Name       : glibc
Name       : glibc-common
Name       : glibc-devel
Name       : glibc-devel
Name       : glibc-headers
Name       : compat-glibc
Name       : compat-glibc
Name       : compat-glibc-headers
Name       : glibc-utils
```

I've bricked Linux boxes in the past by haphazardly installing packages (either via packages or building from source), so I want to know what I'm doing here.

Questions:

1. Since I have glibc-devel already installed, are the debug libraries perhaps already there and I just need to link to them and/or add a compilation switch?
2. If I re-build glibc from source (or install a package) with debugging enabled, how can I be sure not to accidentally brick the machine (i.e. because building the wrong package and triggering library incompatibilities)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Under CentOS, you can install the debug information for a particular package using the `debuginfo-install` command. For example:

```
debuginfo-install glibc
```

For this to work, you need to have the `debuginfo` repository defined.  For CentOS 5, put the following in `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base-debuginfo.repo`:

```
[base-debuginfo]
name=CentOS-$releasever - DebugInfo
baseurl=http://debuginfo.centos.org/$releasever/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=0
protect=1
priority=1
```

*Caveat*: In case you found your way here from Google looking about information for CentOS 6: This works great for CentOS 5.  The CentOS team has had a hard time getting their act together with CentOS 6, and the CentOS 6 debuginfo repositories are out-of-date respect to the most recent packages.  You may or may not be able to find the appropriate debuginfo package for CentOS 6.

Comment: What is the likelihood that doing this will cause dependency hell / incompatibility with other libraries?

Comment: If you are installing packages from the proper repositories using the proper tools (i.e., `yum` and related utilities such as `debuginfo-install`) you should never run into "dependency hell".  Finding yourself fighting dependency problems generally means you've done something wrong.  Installing a `debuginfo` package should generally have no impact on the operation of your system; you're neither installing binaries, libraries, nor config files.

Comment: Perhaps I'm a bit dense here but:
`debuginfo-install glibc` yields `debuginfo-install: command not found` - I'm on CentOS 5.5

Comment: `debuginfo-install` is part of the `yum-utils` package.  If you don't know what package contains a command, you can try something like `yum install /usr/bin/debuginfo-install` and yum will find it for you (assuming that the package you want is in `/usr/bin`)